# SUM of distinct and unique column values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
site      device      site_count    
=================================
1           AB1          45            
1           AB2          45            
1           AB3          45            
1           AB4          45            
1           AB5          45            
2           AB6          70            
2           AB7          70            
2           AB8          70            
3           AB9          100           
3           A10          100           
4           A11          10
```

The below sum(site_count) is obtained by adding  site count value of unique sites i.e 45+70+100+10 =225 (irrespective of no of times the  site appeared).

```
site      device      site_count     sum(site_count)
====================================================
1           AB1          45            225
1           AB2          45            225
1           AB3          45            225
1           AB4          45            225
1           AB5          45            225
2           AB6          70            225
2           AB7          70            225
2           AB8          70            225
3           AB9          100           225
3           A10          100           225
4           A11          10            225
```

Can you post a query to get the sum (site_count) and other columns values in one single query. The result set is displayed above.

Comment: I tried window function but it sums up to 600 that is sum of all site count. Unable to get sum based on distinct site

Comment: Any Help @sql pals...

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to get to. Please could you post an example of your expected result set ? i.e. a single row with totals?

Comment: @Sarin In Question above 1st datagrid is my source table.... 2nd datagrid is my expected output from query. My output should provide sum based on unique sites. Example. site 1 count is 45 though its repeated 4 times while summing it should take it as one.Same for site 2,3,4 the sum should comes as 45+70+100+10 unique site count based on uniqueness of sites.

Comment: I am unable to frame the query as per the output.

Comment: @Sarin I hope u got the question and expected output

Comment: Do you need a statement that works for MySQL **and** Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct on sum:

```
select site, device, site_count, sum(distinct site_count) over ()
from mytable;
```

EDIT: Of course you can do the same without a windowing function, but this may be slower:

```
select site, device, site_count, (select sum(distinct site_count) from mytable)
from mytable;
```

NEW EDIT: I misread your request. In your comment below you've explained that you are not looking for distinct site counts, but merely for the sum of site counts over all sites. So here is an update to my answer.

Unfortunately you don't have one table for sites and one table for devices, as you should, but only a table for devices holding the site count redundantly. You should change that. Having said this, of course even with a disadvantageous data model like yours, it is still possible to select the data. It's only a little more work.

You need the site count once per site. So group by site and take the min, max or avg site count - they should all be the same as the value is stored redundantly. Then sum those site counts:

```
select site, device, site_count, 
(
  select sum(distinct_site_count) 
  from
  (
    select min(site_count) as distinct_site_count from mytable group by site
  )
)
from mytable;
```

Or more compact:

```
select site, device, site_count, 
  (select sum(min(site_count)) from mytable group by site)
from mytable;
```

Comment: Which of the two statements is not working? What error do you get? Both statements look correct to me. AFAIK the first one doesn't work with MySQL, because MySQL doesn't support windowing functions. But it should work in Oracle 11g. And the second statement should work in both dbms.

Comment: See @Thorsten problem is u ve took distinct site_count now for example if site A has a value 45 and site C has a value 45 now out of these two 45 (they are distinct as they belong to two differnet sites) your both queries will take 45 only once. Is it clear now. I am good to go with this : select site, device, site_count, sum(distinct site_count) over ()
from mytable; but provided it meet my  problems mentioned above. Hope u got the issue i am pointing out.